# How to update Azure subscription tags with Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, tags, terraform-provider-azure, azure-subscription

I'm trying to manage Azure tags on the subscription level (not resources or resource groups). We are `not` creating the subscriptions with Terraform and we cannot. After we create the subscription, we create a configuration template for that subscription. In there, we manage things like access control and ownership records. Here's what a standard config template for a subscription looks like.

```
module "subscription-project-pegasus" {
  source                     = "./modules/subscription/"

  subscription_access = [
    {
      aad_group = "all-employees-group"
      role      = "Reader"
    },
    {
      spn = "spn-pegasus"
      role = "Contributor"
    }
  ]

  ownership = {
    team = "Team Pegasus",
    pagerduty_id = "pegasus"
  }
}
```

I would like to add another object here with `tags` that I can apply at the subscription level.

```
tags = {
    owner = "pegasus"
    environment = "nonprod"
  }
```

That custom module `./modules/subscriptions` does the provisioning of role assignments using the `azurerm_role_assignment` module. However, I cannot find a module that can do tagging besides the main [`azurerm_subscription`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subscription#tags) module that's primarily used to provision subscriptions as well. If I use this, I believe Terraform is going to start tracking the state of the subscriptions and that won't be ideal.

I'm looking for a way to add these tags on the subscription level without using the `azurerm_subscription` module. Please advise!

Comment: Are you still not able to find a workaround for it or is it working? @DivZ

Comment: I have not, unfortunately @Jahnavi

Comment: here you provided the module for role assignments along with the tags that you're expected to add.. Is there any info related to the terraform code you tried? @Divz

Comment: The problem is I haven't found any terraform modules to even try this. Only thing is the main `azurerm_subscription` module and that will only work if I'm creating the subscription through terraform as well. I guess I'm asking for people to confirm there is no way to add resource tags through terraform without creating the resource itself in terraform. @VinayB

Comment: Try adding **New-AzTag -ResourceId "/subscriptions/subscriptionId"  -Tag tags owner=Pegasus environment=nonprod** and passing them using  Null resource in terraform configuration. This will resolve the issue in adding the tags to your subscription.

resource "null_resource" "subscription_tags" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      az account set --subscription <subscriptionId>
      az tag create --resource-id /subscriptions/subscriptionId --tags owner=Pegasus environment=nonprod
    EOT
  }
}

Comment: Ok, I will give that a try, thank you!

Comment: have you made any progress? @Divz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to add/update Azure subscription tags with Terraform without using the `azurerm_subscription` module and successfully provisioned the requirement.

If you wish to manage tags on a subscription level without using the `azurerm_subscription` module due to its state tracking, you can achieve this using a local-exec provisioner to run Azure CLI commands to add tags to the subscription.

**My terraform configuation**

##### `main.tf`

```
variable "subscription_id" {
  description = "The ID of the Azure subscription."
  type        = string
}

variable "tags" {
  description = "A map of tags to assign to the resource."
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}


resource "null_resource" "subscription_tags" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      az account set --subscription "${var.subscription_id}"
      az tag create --resource-id "/subscriptions/${var.subscription_id}" --tags ${join(" ", [for k, v in var.tags : "${k}=${v}"])}
    EOT
  }

  triggers = {
    tags = jsonencode(var.tags)
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Here I was using the vinay as owner name and env as non prod]

**Here I was using the `vinay` as the owner name and env as `non-prod`**

[image]

Comment: Looks like that is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much! 
I have one more question - is there anyway this provisioner can update the Terraform state with the tag information as well?